# How to wait for ExecutorService to finish without shutdown?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some `Runnable`s inside ExecutorService, and would like to join the threads after:

```
private void foo() {
  //...
  exec.execute(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      if (bar()) {
        foo();
      }
    }
  });
}

//exec.shutdown()
//exec.awaitTermination();
```

Because it calls itself inside the Runnable so I cannot just shutdown because it may prevent itself to create new tasks.

How can I wait for all threads to finish without shutdown? Is there any way to return a future so I can use `Future::get()`.

Comment: “task does not return a future” makes no sense. Just use `submit` instead of `execute` and you’ll get a `Future`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Executor.submit(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) will return a `Future` that according to the javadoc:

> The Future's get method will return null upon successful completion.

So you can still call `future.get()` and have it block until the task completes.

```
Future<?> future =  exec.submit(new Runnable(){
                                public void run() {
                                       if (bar()) {
                                              foo();
                                       }
                                }
                                });

//blocks
future.get();
```